# Recovering algebraic information about $\mathbb R^n$ from the topology of $\mathbb R P^n$.

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, vector-spaces

One way to define $\mathbb R P^n$ is by identifying it with all $1$-dimensional (linear algebraic) subspaces of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$.

My question is vague because I know very little about this subject, so I'm hoping that others can both clarify the question and provide potential answers or references:

We have (for example) that $\mathbb R P^2$ is nonorientable, it can't be embedded in $\mathbb R^3$, it is compact we can calculate its homology, it fits into the sequence $S^0 \to S^n \to \mathbb R P^n$ etc.

Basically, my point is that there are some interesting things to say about the *shape* or geometry of $\mathbb R P^n$, and I was wondering if there is a useful way to recover or build up some correspondence between these facts and algebraic ones regarding the $1$-subspaces of $\mathbb R$.

**More explicitly:** what are examples of theorems regarding $\mathbb R^n$ as a vector space purely from studying the topological data $\mathbb R P^n$

Comment: Does the second answer here help you?
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2359070/intuitive-geometric-explanation-existence-of-eigenvalue-in-odd-dimension-real-v

I.e., if you have a topological fixed point theorem for a projective space then you should get a theorem about the existence of eigenvalues. This being because linear transformations will induce continuous maps on the underlying projective space. (I'm interested in seeing other examples from more knowledgeable people)

Comment: This is not about $\mathbb{R}^n$ just as a vector space, but the existence of Hurwitz algebra structures on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are related to the topology of $\mathbb{R}P^n$.

Comment: @GeoffreySangston that was a beautiful result

Comment: @JHF would you be willing to elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an elaboration of my comment about certain algebra structures on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and their relationship with the topology of $\mathbb{R}P^{n-1}$.

The connection is this: suppose $A$ is a finite-dimensional division algebra of dimension $n$ over $\mathbb{R}$.  The multiplication on $A$ is a bilinear map $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$.  By linearity, this descends to a map $\mathbb{R}P^{n-1} \times \mathbb{R}P^{n-1} \to \mathbb{R}P^{n-1}$.  Moreover, this map is *axial*, i.e., its restriction to $* \times \mathbb{R}P^{n-1}$ or to $\mathbb{R}P^{n-1} \times *$ is homotopic to the identity.

> **Theorem (Hopf-Stiefel).**
>   An axial map $\mathbb{R}P^{n-1} \times \mathbb{R}P^{n-1} \to \mathbb{R}P^{n-1}$ exists only when $n$ is a power of two.

Its proof is simple.  On mod 2 cohomology, the map induces a ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/2[x]/(x^n) \to \mathbb{Z}/2[a]/(a^n) \otimes \mathbb{Z}/2[b]/(b^n)$.   The axial condition implies that $x \mapsto a + b$.  Therefore, $(a+b)^n \equiv 0 \pmod{2, a^n, b^n}$.  Expanding this using the binomial theorem, this means that $\binom{n}{i}$ is even for $0 < i < n$, which only happens when $n$ is a power of two.

Of course, it's not so surprising that this is a special case of a condition about bilinear maps preserving a quadratic form on Euclidean spaces where the dimensions are allowed to vary.

Here is another theorem of this type, proved using the topological $K$-theory of $\mathbb{R}P^{n-1}$ instead of ordinary cohomology.

> **Theorem (Atiyah).** 
>   An axial map $\mathbb{R}P^{n-1} \times \mathbb{R}P^{n-1} \to \mathbb{R}P^{n-1}$ exists only when $2^{\lfloor (n-1)/2 \rfloor - i + 1}$ divides $\binom{n+i-1}{i}$ for $0 < i \leq \lfloor (n-1)/2 \rfloor$.

In this situation, this is stronger than the Hopf-Stiefel condition.  As a corollary, the Atiyah condition shows

> **Corollary.** 
>   Every finite-dimensional division algebra over $\mathbb{R}$ must have dimension $1$, $2$, $4$, or $8$.

A good reference for this is chapter 12 of *Compositions of quadratic forms* by D.B. Shapiro, which is available on his webpage.

Finally, I can't resist pointing out that these conditions admit generalizations to arbitrary fields that are not of characteristic $2$, due to Dan Dugger and Dan Isaksen.  The strategies are the same, but they use things like motivic cohomology and algebraic $K$-theory of "deleted quadrics", which play the role of real projective spaces there.

Comment: Are there any good places to see an outline of Dugger and Isaksen's theory?

Comment: @MikeMiller I think their papers on the subject [MR2184457, MR2335798, MR2431636] are quite short and readable - the algebraic $K$-theory one is just 10 pages long - and they make the effort to be self-contained.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.