# Determinant-free proof that a real $n \times n$ matrix has at least one real eigenvalue when $n$ is odd.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is there a determinant-free proof that $\textbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ must have at least one real eigenvalue when $n$ is odd?

I have seen a few other definitions of "the set of eigenvalues" which do not invoke the determinant, specifically [the complement of the resolvent set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolvent_set), or the set of points for which $\lambda\textbf{I}_{n \times n} - \textbf{A}$ is singular.

Comment: What do you mean by "for which $\lambda I-A$ is defined"?

Comment: I meant singular, I have fixed it.

Comment: The characteristic polynomial is of odd degree and therefore has at least one real root - perhaps?

Comment: The characteristic polynomial as I know it comes from a determinant. Though, through some searching around I found this paper which is a little bit interesting: https://www.jstor.org/stable/24338320?seq=3#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: Axler's [Down with Determinants](http://www.axler.net/DwD.html) has a proof (the proof of existence of a complex eigenvalue is easy; proving there is a real one requires more knowledge of the structure of the eigendecomposition, and occurs quite late in the paper: Thm 8.2).

Comment: @Chappers +1 for mention of Down with Det.

Comment: @Vim I considered writing an answer, but one has to dig in to stuff about the characteristic polynomial and complexification and so on, so I thought it was better to just recommend the whole paper!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2359070/intuitive-geometric-explanation-existence-of-eigenvalue-in-odd-dimension-real-v

Comment: I don't know what this "down with determinants" craze is all about. Most linear algebra textbooks (Hoffman & Kunze/Lang/Friedberg, Insel & Spence etc.) don't define eigenvalue using determinant. Instead, the eigenvalue is defined as a scalar $\lambda$ such that $Av=\lambda v$ for some $v\ne0$. The determinantal property usually comes as an immediate consequence, not a definition. There is no determinant to "down with" in the first place. In contrast, characteristic polynomial is defined in terms of determinant with a good reason --- such definition works over any commutative ring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a consequence of the [hairy ball theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem).

Given a real $n \times n$ matrix $A$, define a function on the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^n$ by mapping a unit vector $\vec x$ to the component of $A\vec x$ perpendicular to $\vec x$: that is, $$\vec x \mapsto A \vec x - \langle A\vec x, \vec x\rangle \vec x.$$ Being perpendicular to $\vec x$, the result is always tangent to the sphere.

When $n$ is odd, the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^n$ is even-dimensional, and so (by the hairy ball theorem) there is no nonvanishing continuous function with the above property. This means there must be some unit vector $\vec x \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $A \vec x - \langle A\vec x, \vec x\rangle \vec x = \vec 0$: that is, $\vec x$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\langle A\vec x, \vec x\rangle$.

Comment: Axler's *Down with Determinants* proved te existence of eigenvalues without using determinants.

Comment: @Vim Yes, but how is your comment related to the answer here?

Comment: @user1551 I was thinking if eigenvalues are proved to exist then we could just use the other answer's proof which is simpler.

Answer (score 3):

If $A$ is a matrix and 
$$
Av=\lambda v
$$
then we also have 
$$
A\overline{v}=\overline{A}\overline{v}=\overline{Av}=\overline{\lambda v}=\overline{\lambda}\overline{v}
$$
where we use the equality $A=\overline{A}$ because $A$ has real entries. Thus the eigenvalues of $A$ come in complex conjugate pairs, so in particular if $A$ has $2k+1$ eigenvalues, at least $1$ must be real.

Comment: For this to be a complete proof, we need to know that $A$ has any eigenvalues (real or complex) to begin with. This has a determinant-free proof as well (see [this paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.120.08.741) for example) but that is not obvious.

Comment: Thanks for the addition @MishaLavrov . It is something that I have taken for granted for so long that I didn't even think about it, but you are right, that is important